# Starting a browser but should not be shown in recents

Tags: android, android-intent

i am starting the browser with intent using

```
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                startActivity(i);
```

but when i see recent applications i see

> Internet

before my Application.
 I dont want Internet to be shown at all in recent when i launch it as sub-application of mine.
Is there a flag to do so??
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS with your intent

`i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS)`